# Can philosophy make predictions?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, metaphilosophy

Philosophy, one may state, is a field where one makes descriptive statements about the world - whether it's in ethics, metaphysics, logic, or any other philosophical study.

For example "the world is made out of physical entities" is a descriptive statement, and "all bachelor's are not married" is another. While on the contrary, *scientific* statements, one may state, are those of predictive power. Like, for example, "a ball that rolls down the hill would keep on rolling until something stops it", and "if a man that changes social groups, his social status would probably change, more often than a man that stays within his original social group".

Is this distinction between *philosophical* statements and *scientific* statements correct? Do philosophical enquiries not have predictive power?

EDIT:

Just to be clear, this question isn't about what differentiate philosophy from science; I merely use science as a contrast to something that doesn't involve prediction (as most would say that prediction is science's goal).

Comment: The statements you provided are not philosophical but linguistical. That means they define relationships between words/notions.

Comment: Isn't reducing philosophy to "descriptive statements", well, reductive? Isn't its role more of tying up diverse experiences into a structured whole? Sciences also make plenty of  "descriptive statements", positivists even thought that that is what its experimental basis consists of. And description, if accurate, is predictive of what it describes. "All bachelor's are not married" is analytic by the usual lights rather than descriptive.

Comment: @Conifold I agree with every word, I couldn't think of this description myself but knew there was something wrong with my wordings. And still, "tying up diverse experiences into a structured whole" - can this make a prediction?

Comment: It can, but perhaps more importantly, it helps with explaining and deciding how to act. So while philosophy can make predictions that is not its primary function. Once predictions in some area become specific enough it splits off into a positive science.

Comment: "predictions" about what ?

Comment: In Tractaus Wittgenstein said that Scientists used another world to define this world. So there is no proof whether a scientific discovery is right or wrong but it's just and just an application of language.

Comment: @Conifold "it can". Can you give me an example?

Comment: "[Multiple realizability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/multiple-realizability/) is the correct way to view mental states, therefore if we continue to search we will eventually discover other entities that have different physical kinds that produce the same mental kind as us." that is obviously an empirical prediction. You are cheating with words in how you framed philosophy as being descriptive but science as predictive. Science is also descriptive, and we use those descriptions to make predictions. You can do the same exact thing with philosophy.

Comment: Here's a better way to say what you said: "Balls that roll down hills continue to roll down hills until something stops them. Therefore, if I were to roll this ball down this hill, it will continue to roll until something stops it." Obviously that is drawing a prediction from a descriptive statement.

Comment: Verifiable predictions are one thing that helps identify whether the idea is right/wrong. This helps us decide whether we should follow that path of the idea or modify/change the idea so that the modified/changed predictions are true. It seems to be the tradition in science that any idea/theory should have verifiable predictions otherwise it is not considered to be a scientific idea/theory. It seems that this is not the tradition in philosophy – one can propose an idea, and, as long as it is logical, it is acceptable even if it is without any verifiable predictions to prove its correctness.

Comment: Philosophy is respect for obtaining knowledge, and that is all it is. Predictions, and the issuing of them are another matter altogether. Either philosophy or science (i.e. observation, hypothesis & peer review) may inform prediction.

Comment: Kant's prediction about Euclidean geometry (and Newtonian mechanics) famously got him into a world of trouble. More recent bits of philosophy of mind and language with empirical consequences include Chomsky's universal grammar, Fodor's language of thought, and Kripke's causal theory of reference for names and natural kinds. There is a whole new field of [experimental philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_philosophy). But notably physical, chemical, and biological issues are rarely included now, unlike in the natural philosophy times, that split off.

Comment: This is a side issue but the conclusion of the linked Multiple Realizability  article seems to be the opposite:"*The assumption that multiple realizability “seals the deal” against reductive physicalism and the type identity theory of mind was misplaced initially, and is now even more misplaced after the second wave of recent criticisms*".  Regardless of type physicalism, the idea of "the same" mental kinds across vastly different creatures does sound very fishy.

Comment: @Conifold I was just giving a link to the topic. Whether or not that article argues for the opposite conclusion, what I described is still a prediction someone could make. I highly disagree with multiple realizability, it always seemed fishy to me and I especially wasn't convinced by the modal arguments from conceivability, but again my point is that it is still a prediction someone could make, whether or not it turns out to be true.

Comment: I've realized the foolishness of this question, as what I essentially want to ask here is whether philosophy can be verifiable, which is a topic well-discussed in many questions here on the site. The question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy makes countless predictions but whether these are the sort of predictions you mean I'm not sure. They are the results of analysis but may serve as predictions.

This is an off-the-cuff scrappy list but by its results philosophy predicts...

--it is impossible to establish the objective reality of phenomena or discover an 'essence' at their core.

--there is no way to show how consciousness arises from matter.

--physics will never be able to refute or verify solipsism

--a matter-only theory is not fundamental. Materialism is false.

--a mind-only theory is not fundamental. Subjective Idealism is false.

--physics will never discover a fact that contradicts a result of metaphysical analysis.

--physics (as currently defined) will never have a fundamental theory.

--the metaphysical existence of time and space will never be established.

There are many more but whether they would count as predictions in the sense asked by the question may be moot.

Comment: By "philosophy predicts", do you mean "almost all philosophers agree that"?  What about "a result of metaphysical analysis" - particularly considering that space, time, and causality were all seriously revised in the Twentieth Century?

Comment: @DavidThornley - I mean that philosophy predicts in the same way as mathematics. Mathematics 'predicts' that if I add 20 apples to 50 apples I'll have 70 apples. By analysis we establish the absurdity of metaphysical positions and theories and so 'predict' their falsity. I concede that this is not what the OP may have meant by 'predict'.  .

Comment: Mathematics doesn't predict that.  It says that 20 + 50 is 70.  There are lots of things that don't actually add.  If you have one drop of water and add one drop of water, you've got one drop of water.  If you take two appropriately-shaped pieces of weapons-grade U-235 and bang them together sufficiently hard, and bring everything back together, you will find you've lost some mass.  We know empirically that, under normal circumstances (i.e., not dropping into a black hole) apples add like integers.

Comment: @DavidThornley   Yes. Mathematics predicts that apples add like integers. Or, at least, mathematicians do. I did note that this sort of prediction might not qualify but still I think a case can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Classically philosophers have disagreed on this, and it has as much to do with the changing  *social status* of philosophy (as a field of literature or an academic discipline) than anything else. Before approximately 1800, *anyone* who was making important predictions about nature or society would be called a "natural philosopher" or a "moral philosopher". Since then, largely due to the influence of Kant, an idea has spread that philosophy is sort of the command-center of all forms of theoretical inquiry, grappling with the limits of human reason and what we can legitimately infer; as soon as philosophers manage to spin off a sub-field of philosophy with its own proper theoretical tools and conceptual apparatus, then that sub-field stops being part of philosophy and becomes an "empirical science".

Anyway, without boring you with the history (which, as I've implied, combined sociological changes and philosophical changes in odd ways), the basic conceptions philosophers seem to have today:

1. Philosophers investigate the same sorts of questions as empirical scientists but using  different approaches/methods/background training.
2. Philosophers investigate the same topics as empirical researchers, but there is a clean division of the questions (philosophy handles the questions that can't be answered or can't be described in empirical terms: so no predictions)
3. Philosophers investigate different topics, skew to what empirical research is able to look into (again, the topics don't lend themselves to prediction, verification, or falsification)
4. Philosophy and the empirical sciences kiss on their borders, so that e.g. an abstract metaphysical analysis of space could turn out to be crucial for theoretical physics.

My concluding caution would be: just because *you* can't follow/conceive what a position's implications (empirical or logical) are, doesn't  mean it doesn't have implications.